# Ontology - how to say instance of a class "must have" something?

Tags: ontology, protege

I'm creating an Ontology in Protege 5.1, solving a real problem, for the first time.

I'm stumbling on the basic need to making certain types of properties "required" for an instance of a class. I'd like to Reasoner to highlight problems like a missing required property.

So let's say a certain class of products e.g. "Physical Products" require a "Weight". How can I express this requirement in the ontology? So that Physical Products without a Weight would be flagged?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that **you cannot do that with OWL**.

OWL ontologies describe truth about the world, **nothing else**. Ontologies do not make the screen flash, they do not impose regulations on what to give to the policeman to verify you are a person, and they do not make ontology systems break because what is known to exist is not provided with a concrete value. Ontologies are knowledge, not regulations. If I know as a fact that physical products must have weight, there is no reason my mental reasoner should freak out because the apple I carry does not provide an explicit value of its weight.

However, if you have verifiable proof that a physical product does not have a weight, such as a person trying to sell you an abstract concept as if it was a physical product that you can touch and handle, then you can say that there is an inconsistency. That is, there are truths that are contradicting each others. Reasoners can detect inconsistencies and explain the reason for inconsistency. However, they would not be able to flag the absence of weight as the reason for the inconsistency.

Still, this is probably not satisfying to you because you have a concrete problem and you want a concrete solution. One way of dealing with this is simply to implement the requirements. If you cannot find a value for the weight, possibly even using a reasoner, then you flag the instance that fails to provide its weight. A more elaborate solution is to declare integrity constraints using Pellet. Pellet is using an extension of OWL that allows one to declare integrity constraints of the kind you are interested in (e.g., required values). There may be other non standard extensions or tools that can specify what you need, but all this is outside the scope of OWL and RDF(S).

Answer (score 2):

The thing you want to achieve is typically done using SPARQL.

You can write a SPARQL query that will return all "Physical Products" that doesn't have a "Weight" (using NOT EXISTS {...}). Then you can "flag" the elements returned. Note that what you mean by "flag" is not clear.

A good way to play with this is to use SPARQL rules such as SPIN. This non-standard extension allows to use SPARQL queries as constraints on your data. It is well integrated in Topbraid Composer... even the free edition if I'm correct.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Existential restriction (i.e. some). In description logic, it can be stated as:
    = 3PhysicalProducts.requireWeight U ~(3PhysicalProducts.requireWeight)

```
The sign 3 is the some restriction;
U is logical OR;
~ is the negation;
```